# Photo attached of flies ‘injecting’ into spider egg sacs. Why? What’s going on here?

Tags: zoology, behaviour, arachnology, parasitology

Brisbane, Australia.

While no image is available, direct observations were made of flies doing *something* to the egg sac.

[image: Spider nest, with flies ‘injecting’ into egg sacs]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. What makes you think the flies are 'injecting' something into the structure? Also please give us any information you have relevant to [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) — in particular it could be helpful to know the geographic location as well as the ids of the species involved (if known).

Comment: Possibly cannot see in the photo, but I could see each fly had a part of themselves extended from their rear end going into the egg sacs.        She is a ‘tent spider’ and that’s how they lay their eggs. Each ‘bump’ is a sac of eggs.

Comment: Cyrtophora moluccensis- tent spider.
Injecting? I could see something from the rear end of the flies going into the sac. (Sorry, Not clear in photo).                                        Location: Brisbane Australia

Answer (score 5):

(Converting from comment)

Based on internet searches, it appears likely that the fly is [*Sarcophaga arachnivora*](https://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/v3/Sarcophaga/key/australian_sarcophaga/Media/Html/Sarcophaga_(Baranovisca)_arachnivora.htm), which lives off of spider egg cases in its juvenile form; the fly is laying eggs.

If you follow that link you will see references to a couple of papers that describe the species in more detail, though I don't believe I have access to them.

The geographic location noted there of SE Australia agrees with your observation of the organism.

[References about tent spiders](https://www.qm.qld.gov.au/Explore/Find+out+about/Animals+of+Queensland/Spiders/Modern+Spiders+Infraorder+Araneomorphae/Orb-weaving+spiders/Tent+spiders) also make note of parasitic "flesh flies" so the species interaction appears to be an established phenomenon.